# Can I make a regulated power supply that has two different output voltages?

Tags: power, 24v

Can I use a single 24 V, 110 V / 220 V AC to DC universal regulated switching power supply to power two different components? One which requires 12 V and the other which is 14.8 V?

I have a project wherein the main component, a water pump, requires 12 V and the second component is a linear actuator which requires 14.8 V. I would like them both to be powered by a single AC to DC universal regulated switching power supply such as the [DROK 48 V Power Supply, AC 110 V / 220 V to DC 0-48 V 5 A 240 W buck converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B3J7V7M6).

Comment: Listed below? Where? Is there a missing link?

Comment: It depends on how much current they take.

Comment: you can use a buck module to turn 14.8v to 12.0v, probably your best bet. Or try to run them both at 13.5 or something like that.

Comment: Type numbers / specifications of the water pump and the linear actuator would be of help in arriving at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check the voltage range specifications, they probably overlap. If so supply power in overlapping voltage range and viola only one power supply. Those voltages are probably nominal ratings and you will find a large latitude of voltages that will work.

Those power supplies come in a range of output voltages, The one you link to is adjustable. Look at a 15V power supply, it should be a good fit.